# Why is my main domain redirecting to subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) on goDaddy for which I have a hosted zone on AWS Route 53

In my hosted zone, example.com & [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) was pointed to a website on Wix and sub domain app.example.com to AWS cloudfront distribution ( let's say app.cluodfront.net ). Now I want to point both [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and app.example.com to my cloudfront dist.

**Previously I had:**
A record - example.com pointed to Wix
A record - app.example.com pointed to app.cloudfront.net (alias)
CNAME record -  [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) pointed to Wix

**Now I've changed them to:**
A record - example.com to app.cloudfront.net (alias)
A record - app.example.com pointed to app.cloudfront.net (alias)
A record - [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to app.cloudfront.net (alias) ( deleted the previous CNAME record )

**Problem:**
Whenever I go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), it redirects to app.example.com, but I don't want that.
I want all example.com/www.example.com/app.example.com to serve from my cloudfront distribution without redirecting

Comment: Without knowing your actual URL it is hard for us to provide a definitive answer to your question bro,

What I will say is that are you editing the entries and zones on the right name server? Reading between the lines you've swapped nameservers to stop using goDaddys and start using cloudflare, so goDaddy owns your domain name but now cloudfare (should) be providing the administrator panel for them if you set up the name servers correctly.
* Nameserver config - thats the first thing to check

Comment: * Second, if you did move from one to another, then depending on that all important propagation, it can take minutes or sometimes several hours (I once waited nearly 36) for dns propogation to have gone all over the globe.

I mention this because it seems though you are still seeing the old behaviour, and you're now expecting to see something different. But that won't happen unless the dns changes have been propagated properly

Comment: "do you have any suggestion on how to achieve what I want, " Ask your registrat, DNS provider and/or website hoster. Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming and impossible to reply as you hide any useful details. " I can't share the URL for obvious reasons." No there are no obvious reasons nor reasons at all, the DNS is public, names are known, there is no point hiding them and especially if you hope to get relevant help (but not here as your question is offtopic)

Comment: @Noscere DNS propagation is wrong terminology as it mostly doesn't exist. You can do changes and if you test on authoritative nameservers you see the changes immediately.

Comment: @Noscere Thanks mate, appreciate your time.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek No use dude, utterly useless - your comments.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek yes you're right, I've seen the same whilst testing my own site(s) - but then I do have 8.8.4.4 manually configured instead of relying on DHCP, and not everyone knows how to set their DNS up properly - they can cope with entering everything manually (static IP, DNS, etc), or automatic - but their brain explode when you try to get them to keep the automatic IP but manually configure the DNS. Like, half-n-half is too much to handle. On a tangent here, I got the same head-explode reaction once when I topped up a half-full glass of orange juice (frm concentrate) with blackcurrant.

Comment: (continued..) I used to just rely on my ISP DNS, but started manually providing 8.8.4.4 (or 1.0.0.1, etc - we're free not to use google if thats your bag   after having a big issue - my site changes still not reflected after a couple hrs; I'd allowed for double the TTL and still nada - was when I  hardcoded my 8.8.4.4 - and started with 300s TTLs. 

I also wondered if it was worse using default NS of completely free TLD's provided by freenom.com - such as .tk, .gq, etc. I started pointing new domains to a 3rd party nameserver (such as google cloud DNS - I also like porkbuns interface)

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone facing similar issue:**
Make sure your new domains/subdomains are added under your cloudfront distribution. It's just a simple step which I missed.